# Canceling task if a parallel task throw an exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have two parallel tasks that share the same cancellation token, the client asks for two lists of result like:

```
class ResponseDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<Entity1> Entity1List { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Entity2> Entity2List { get; set; }
}
```

The two requests are calculated simultaneously and depended, so if one of the list is has no result there no need to wait for the other result.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;

Task task1 = new Task(() =>
{
    //fetch Entity1 results into entity1List

    if (!entity1List.Any())
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
    else
    {
        responseDTO.Entity1List = entity1List;
    }
}, token);

Task task2 = new Task(() =>
{
    //fetch Entity2 results into entity2List

    if (!entity2List.Any())
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
    else
    {
        responseDTO.Entity2List = entity2List;
    }
}, token);

task1.Start();
task2.Start();

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(new[] { task1, task2 }, token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
{
    return responseDTO;
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
        //Log the exception
    return responseDTO;
}

return responseDTO;
```

In case of the tasks has returned an empty list the canceling works fine.

**My question** is: how to cancel one of the tasks if the other one threw a general exception?

Comment: You could request cancellation if exception occur and then in another task query for the `toke.IsCancelationRequested`...

Comment: I'm asking about monitoring other exceptions (not cancel exceptions)

Comment: You can introduce try/catch blocks in your `//fetch` code and call `cts.Cancel();` inside the catch

Comment: Pass a single cancellation token to all the tasks, then in an catch block, cancel that cancellation token, this will abort other tasks that are still executing, assuming you've correctly written the code to take the cancellation token into account.

Comment: As @LasseVågsætherKarlsen said if there is the code in place to cancel the task, task won't be cancelled automatically once they are started. You have to implement that code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with @noobed comment.

```
try
{
    //fetch Entity1 results into entity1List
}
catch
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

In case of general exception it will be catch, and the cts can be called with cancel.